# Apache2 as simple https proxy

Tags: https, proxy, apache2

I’ll just briefly explain what I have and what I’d like.

On same server I have a service which has also a web gui on http port 9091 for example. The service does not have a option to change the config to https within the app.

I also have apache on that server for snmp traps graphs. So I’d like to use that apache as a https proxy, so communication to apache is https, from apache to that mentioned web plain http.

Client <-> https proxy <-> http web ui

I don’t want just redirect.

Can you advise me a simple solution. Not lucky yet with search.

Thank you!
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Worked with

```
<VirtualHost *:8843>
    ServerName xxx
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#        DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine On
    # Set the path to SSL certificate
    # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /xxx.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /XXX.key
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission
    ProxyPassReverse /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission
```